# Get entity assert property in form view (or in form builder) to use with JS

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to access assert information defined in entity class from a form

```
class MyEntity {
  [...]
  /*
   * @Assert\Count(min="1", max="3")
   */
  protected $myfield;
  [...]
}
```

The purpose is to customize the view.
In this example, I would like to display a message that said "you must enter between [min] and [max] items"

I var_dumped a lot of variable in form_div_layout.html.twig
I've tried to explore the FormBuilder object but I haven't found this.

Do you know a way to achieve this ?

PS: sorry for my poor english

EDIT AFTER Martin Rios answer:

The goal is not to provide error message.

The final goal is to use these values for the construction of the view.

For example, if you use this jQuery plugin: [sfPrototypeMan](https://github.com/wiese/jquery-sfPrototypeMan), you can have an "add item" link and a "remove item".

If I want to disable the "add item" link when my collection reaches its maximum size, I need to manipulate constraint property in my JavaScript

I tried to study this plugin [JsFormValidatorBundle](https://github.com/formapro/JsFormValidatorBundle) but didn't understood how it works...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it like the [Validation in the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html) ?

Is far more easier than to do it inside your Entities. And at the same time you have the benefit of not having your entities coupled to Symfony.

```
# src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\MyEntity:
    properties:
        myfield:
            - Count:
               min: 1
               max: 3
               minMessage: "You must specify at least one item"
               maxMessage: "You cannot specify more than {{ limit }} items"
```

Make sure the property you are validating is a collection's (i.e. an array or an object that implements Countable)

EDITED after the edition of chakhâl :
You don't need to overcomplicate things, if you want to access it from somewhere just keep this values in parameters.yml and do a [Custom form Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)
AFAIK you cannot use a variable defined in parameters.yml on the validation otherwise this will be very easy.

But I try to keep always in mind, that forms are forms, and views are different things. So if you want to keep things simple, just pass this min / max values as an additional template array, and define it in the parameters.yml. Only if you need to go deeper, then inject them in a custom validator and have them in a single place (But it sounds like overcomplicating things a bit in my personal opinion)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I think that the annotations in my message is equivalent to your syntax.
The goal is not to display error message, but to used these value for the building of the view.
I will edit my message to be more precise.

Comment: I'm not sure to be really clear, but my question is not about validation.
It's about displaying message related to validation but before the user submit data (it's more about ergonomics: prevent error rather detect them)

Comment: I understand what you mean. But @Assert\Count(min="1", max="3") is for validation. And that value is accessed/checked only after submitting. Then if you want to prevent, just define this value somewhere else and pass it as a parameter in your view. The way you defined the question initially was all about validation.

Comment: I'm agree with the fact that my post can be a little confusing (because I'm trying to display message that is usually display after validation).

In the formview, you can access the value and then the underlying entity.

I think that I'm not so far of the solution (I suppose the mechanism used at validation time can be reproduce).

It's true that I can pass manually the value to the view but as this is already defined in the entity I'd like to get them.

I believe that another way to ask for this could be: "how would you implement client side validation using entity metadatas ?"